# Mule ESB, returning the Database Connector data in a JSON like format

Tags: json, rest, http, mule, esb

I have a simple flow, that receives a REST, but without any corresponding data being input to the flow

The following is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TEST:user=instuid;password=instpw;" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
    <flow name="test2Flow1" doc:name="test2Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database" doc:description="test">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT ACCTNUM FROM xxx.ACCOUNT]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The SQL from the command line (outside of Mule) returns the following:

```
db2 => SELECT ACCTNUM FROM xxx.ACCOUNT

ACCTNUM
----------
11111
22222
```

The flow then executes a fully configured Database Connector, The data ten is passed to the outbound http connector:

```
C:\curl>curl http://localhost:8081
¼φ ♣sr ¶java.util.LinkedList♀)S]J`ê"♥  xpw♦   ☻sr $org.mule.util.CaseInsensitive
HashMap¥╤┘∩gE╬ ♥  xpw♀?@     ►   ☺t ACCTNUMt
11111     xsq ~ ☻w♀?@     ►   ☺q ~ ♦t
22222     xx
```

...so you can see that it is getting the variables from the table '11111' and '22222'.

What I don't know yet is what to do now.  I want to take the result of the Database Connector, and return the strings '11111' and '22222'. in a JSON like format, but I do not know how to do that

Could someone please tell me the exasiest way to do that, and perhaps provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are going right .... Just put a Object to JSON Transformer after the DB connector at the end like   `<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>` ... see the following :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TEST:user=instuid;password=instpw;" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
    <flow name="test2Flow1" doc:name="test2Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database" doc:description="test">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT ACCTNUM FROM xxx.ACCOUNT]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
  <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```